# Objective-C: Remove duplicates efficiently from large data structures

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, duplicates, nsorderedset

I have an object containing an array of `NSNumbers` (`indexes`) and an array of `NSDictionaries` (`indexesTitles`) corresponding to `indexes`, containing some info.
I have to call a method for each `object.index` and associate `object.indexTitles` to the returning results, saving them into a single array.
At the end of it, I want to remove indexes duplicates, preserving the associated `indextTitles` in an efficient way, because I'm working with large arrays.

```
NSMutableArray *resultArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *titlesArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for(NSNumber *index in object.indexes)
{
    NSArray *resultsIndexArray = [self methodThatReturnsAnArray];
    NSString *indexTitleDictionary = [object.indexesTitles objectAtIndex:i];
    for(NSNumber *resultId in resultsIndexArray)
    {
        [titlesArray addObject:indexDictionary];
        [resultArray addObject:resultId];
    }
    i++;
}
[fullResultsArray addObject:titlesArray];
[fullResultsArray addObject:resultArray];
```

I've found that the most efficient way to remove duplicates is using an
NSOrderedSet like this:

```
NSOrderedSet *orderedSet = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:resultArray];
resultArray = [orderedSet.array mutableCopy];
```

How can I remove the corresponding entries in `titlesArray`? how can I preserve the association?
I've also tried to use a `NSDictionary` like `{resultId, titleDictionary}` and storing them into an array, but I haven't found a efficient way to remove dictionaries with the same `result`, they are all too slow.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Use `NSMutableSet` instead of `NSMutableArray` to eliminate duplicates.

Comment: can you please expand your comment with some details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not completely clear to me what your problem is, maybe this will help:

A good way to remove duplicates is not to add them in the first place, replace:

```
for(NSNumber *resultId in resultsIndexArray)
{
    [titlesArray addObject:indexDictionary];
    [resultArray addObject:resultId];
}
```

with:

```
for(NSNumber *resultId in resultsIndexArray)
{
    // only add if resultId not already in resultArray
    if( ![resultArray containsObject:resultId] )
    {
        [titlesArray addObject:indexDictionary];
        [resultArray addObject:resultId];
    }
}
```

The `containsObject:` call requires a linear search, if your data set is large you might wish to change `resultArray` to an `NSMutableSet` and `titlesArray` to an `NSMutableDictionary` mapping from `resultId` to `indexDictionary` values.

HTH

Comment: Thanks @CRD, I am trying your second solution, the problem is the in the NSMutableDictionary like {resultId, indexDictionary} I'm getting the last values of indexdictionary, I need the first occurrence instead, how can I manage that?

Comment: Solved, I've just added  if(![titlesDictionary objectForKey:resultId]), then set object for the key.